# Please Explain the Debt to China

Tags: china, money-management

Can someone please explain to me how we are in debt with China? Every weblog, article, journal I read have people in the comments going insane about how we "owe China monies" and "China owns the US" or how the world is being taken over by China!!

From my understanding we sell bonds to the open market (like most countries and businesses) and China is just one country in a laundry-list of countries that buy these bonds. These bonds are also NOT the same as debt right? I just don't know why people say that we "owe too much money to china" What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is roughly what countries own US treasuries:

http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/tic/Documents/mfh.txt

As you can see China owns a lot.  In fact they own way more than any other nation.  Why does China own so many?  Because of the trade deficit between the US and China.  What's that?  China has gotten all of it's fortune by being the factory that makes things for other companies.  China is the factory of the world.  Hence whenever a product in the world is created more than likely the Chinese had some hand in building it.  Every IPod, IPad, Android Phone, etc sold has to be bought from China because they made it.  The act of buying those products produced outside your countries borders is called importing.  The USA imports goods from China.  Now in theory the USA should be manufacturing things that China wants and hence because we are in a good trade relationship (we're not again theory), China would buy things from us that we manufacture.  Say cars, windows software, mac os software, etc.  The fact of the matter is that the US is buying way more stuff from China than they are buying from the US.  This creates a the trade deficit.  A trade deficit means more money is moving out of the USA and into China.

How does a nation get rich?  By exporting more than they import.  Across all of it's trading partners the USA is importing vastly more than exporting.  In fact the USA can't really pay for everything it's importing each year, and the US government is running debt over it's spending thanks to social security (funded, but poorly), medicare (not directly funded - big problem), and the military (DOD spending accounts for ~60% of all government spending).  So to cover these losses it has to borrow money from the Treasury.  When the US borrows money from the Treasury it issues that in terms of US Treasury bonds.  A bond says 'Let me have $100 today, and I'll pay you back $103 tomorrow.'  In order for the US to pay its debts someone has to buy our bonds to get that $100.  Who is doing that?

Well China is making tons of money.  Where do they park that money so it can grow and earn interest?  Countries aren't like you and I in this regard.  They don't hop down to bank and dump their money in there.  Instead they buy debt from other countries.  The best debt and most stablest debt in the world is US Treasury Debt because they've never defaulted and they are the richest country in the world.  Because of that their currency is really predictable and doesn't have crazy inflation.  To protect that money China owns **China buys US Treasury bonds**.  And they've been doing this for 40 years or more.  So US is buying China's goods with China's money and promising to pay China back at a later date.  China is happy to do this because they can safely earn an almost guaranteed interest on their money keeping it safe from inflation.

Another reason China does this, and really the primary reason is to keep their inflation low.  When China sells goods into the US it gets paid in dollars, but ultimately it wants Renminbi so under normal circumstances it would exchange dollars for Renminbi and then import that money back into China.  When this happens it will raise the demand for Renminbi, and trade will balance out as China's currency rises.  This eliminates trade imbalances, except that China doesn't do that.  They've been buying US bonds from dollars they have rather than buying Renminbi.  This keeps the money out of the China banking system so it doesn't experience inflation.  That is how China "manipulates" their currency is by buying foreign bonds keeping the money from causing inflation in their country.  China has dialed back their rate of buying US bonds around 2013 or 2014 so they are letting their currency rise more than in the past.  They really aren't manipulating their currency like they were in the past.

This is why the argument over the debt ceiling is really really important.  The debt ceiling is what allows the US government to keep borrowing money.  There is a US law that says the US government will never borrow more than X.  And they rewrite that law every time the US needs to borrow more than X (it's been rewritten a lot <strike>for like 30 years</strike> since 1980s - except for 1998-2001 where it ran surpluses).  They are in the process of rewriting that law now to up the debt ceiling to Y, and they're playing an ideological war over all the shit they argue about.  In the end they have to raise it because there is no other option, but they're playing a game of chicken with each other.  If they didn't we would default on paying back debt.  Essentially, the holders of those US bonds wouldn't get $103 back, and they'd be really super pissed off.  This could cause US holders of debt to rethink it call in early payment on that debt.

If China decides to call in the debt the US has to pay them and would have a shortage of funds to pay that debt.  The US would be absolutely screwed.  Remember the US doesn't have any money because it's been selling US bonds to get money, so the US can't get money because it just defaulted on the one thing that brings in the money.  And who's gonna want to buy them?  If this came to pass and it would ruin the USA.  This would be financial system Armageddon because China (and others) owns so much of our money.  We owe them so much money that we'd never pay them back for the next century or two.  That kind of debt is basically financial slavery.  We're talking 100 years of the Great Depression type conditions.  Huge inflation, US money would be worthless.  It'd make Zimbabwe look like a stable investment.

Now what holds this altogether is that having the US falter like that would take everyone down because everyone looses their money.  US owes everyone so every dollar we make of GDP would go right out the window to our debt holders, and their savings would be obliterated because we defaulted.  This is the end of the world as we know it type stuff should it come to pass.

Comment: This could be the best answer to any question on the stackexchange network. Thorough, detailed, smart, and so very informative. I hope that many many people see this answer and become smarter. Thank you so much for explaining this to me and making me INFORMED! All the best!

Comment: So I don't get why politicians are letting this happen? It seems very bad position for us to be in and maintain any kind of superpower status. Could it be that people are right and China will one day "take over the US" (as a superpower).

Comment: Here is an interesting article about how this game of chicken is playing out.  They've both screwed themselves by pandering their constituencies and whipping up the troops over something that shouldn't be this big of a deal.  Don't get me wrong we really need to stop raising the ceiling, but now is not the time to think about standing our ground.  This is a long term thing that has to be planned.

http://articles.cnn.com/2011-07-11/opinion/gergen.debt.crisis_1_tax-collectors-president-obama-national-debt?_s=PM:OPINION

Comment: -1: This post contains several factual errors (e.g. please provide supporting studies that show trade deficits cause nations to become poorer).  It also only represents a extreme mercantilist view.  It would have been nice to note that a big reason China exports so much and buys so many Treasury bonds is that it pegs the Yuan to the USD.  Regardless, this question is very off-topic for this site.

Comment: Fair enough.  It's a very simplified explanation.  I'll give you that Joshua.  We would be getting poorer if the moneys America owned were fixed.  But they aren't.  In fact our GDP continues to grow despite having all this debt.  The debt we have reduces potential growth by a little, but we continue to grow by 2-3% / year.  So if we're growing we aren't really getting poorer right?  The real problem with debt is the sustainability of it.  How long can we keep selling debt to pay our debts without raising taxes on its citizens? Nobody knows, but we are reaching close to owing what our GDP is.

Comment: The pegging of the yuan to the dollar thing complicated the answer because you have to explain foreign currency differences and how that affects prices on goods.  I couldn't tie it up into a simple explanation so I left it out.  Plus this is just a short primer if you really want to learn more you need to do more investigation.  I think though this answer let's everyday people roughly understand the topic to follow along with global financial news.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich if it's off-topic fine, have it deleted. Chubbard gave me enough info for me to go research on my own and find out more.

Comment: @robertlewis2001: you'd be much better served by starting with this [Wikipedia article on the balance of trade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_trade).  It provides more than the [mercantilist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercantilism) view.  You would also benefit from understanding the [current account](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_account) and [balance of payments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_payments) and avoiding nonsense spouted on in the global financial news (except publications like The Economist and Financial Times).

Comment: @joshua Ulrich Thanks for the assistance. I really didn't know this question was off-topic until I read more about the forum.

Comment: US can default only if they choose to (for example, not wanting to rise debt ceiling), US can always pay it's debt because its denominated in US dollars. On the other hand Greece can't as they own foreign currency. This answer is completely wrong, the author doesn't understand the monetary system of US. Unfortunately for US, politicians don't understand it as well. I would suggest you look at MMT, modern monetary theory for valid explanations of debt.